# Fast text file parsing in java

Tags: java, parsing, file-io, text-files

I have a number of text files which are in a fixed, repeated format like:

```
Q 32,0 16
q 27
b 21
I 0
P 1
d 0
m 31,0
Q 48,0 16
q 27
b 2
I 2
P 1
d 0
m 31,0
.
.
.
```

I want to parse them in Java. What I want to know is the fastest method to parse such a text file. I can change the output format of the text file if that helps with the performance, as the only requirement here is speed of parsing.
I can use external libraries too.

Comment: Using Scanner is too slow for you?

Comment: @Thihara Yes, in fact I am using Scanner itself. For some cases where the size of the text file is relatively small, like 3-4000 lines, the performance is OK, but when I get to large files, like 30-40000 lines, the performance is not that good and something that I would like to improve.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest speed of parsing is to use a binary format. I sugegst you use native byte order and you should be able to read about 20 million entries per second for this sort of data.

---

An example of reading and writing binary data with a high throughput AND low latency is here.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

This format is designed to be read as it is written (with less than one micro-second latency between processes)

You could use a simpler format than this as I suspect all you need is high throughput. ;)

BTW: The library supports GC-less read and writing of text such as `long` and `double` values directory to/from a memory mapped ByteBuffer. As such it can be used as a fast text logger supporting over one million realistic text messages per second.

Comment: Same here, an example would go a long way in explaining how to use it.. :)

Comment: Same here I also wanna see now! :-D

Comment: Added an example from a library I wrote. See the README section of the home page for results.